# Find One to N is Prime optimization

Tags: c++, math, optimization, primes, largenumber

So I was inspired by a recent Youtube video from the Numberphile Channel. [This one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKlVNFOHJ9I) to be exact. Cut to around the 5 minute mark for the exact question or example that I am referring to.

TLDR; A number is created with all the digits corresponding to *1 to **N***. Example: 1 to 10 is the number 12,345,678,910. Find out if this number is prime. According to the video, ***N*** has been checked up to 1,000,000.

From the code below, I have taken the liberty of starting this process at 1,000,000 and only going to 10,000,000. I'm hoping to increase this to a larger number later.

So my question or the assistance that I need is optimization for this problem. I'm sure each number will still take very long to check but even a minimal percentage of optimization would go a long way.

Edit 1: Optimize which division numbers are used. Ideally this divisionNumber would only be prime numbers.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

namespace
{
    int myPow(int x, int p)
    {
        if (p == 0) return 1;
        if (p == 1) return x;
        if (p == 2) return x * x;

        int tmp = myPow(x, p / 2);
        if (p % 2 == 0) return tmp * tmp;
        else return x * tmp * tmp;
    }

    int getNumDigits(unsigned int num)
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (num != 0)
        {
            num /= 10;
            ++count;
        }
        return count;
    }

    unsigned int getDigit(unsigned int num, int position)
    {
        int digit = num % myPow(10, getNumDigits(num) - (position - 1));
        return digit / myPow(10, getNumDigits(num) - position);
    }

    unsigned int getTotalDigits(int num)
    {
        unsigned int total = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
            total += getNumDigits(i);
        return total;
    }

    // Returns the 'index'th digit of number created from 1 to num
    int getIndexDigit(int num, int index)
    {
        if (index <= 9)
            return index;

        for (int i = 10; i <= num; i++)
        {
            if (getTotalDigits(i) >= index)
                return getDigit(i, getNumDigits(i) - (getTotalDigits(i) - index));

        }
    }

    // Can this be optimized?
    int floorSqrt(int x)
    {

        if (x == 0 || x == 1)
            return x;

        int i = 1, result = 1;
        while (result <= x)
        {
            i++;
            result = i * i;
        }
        return i - 1;
    }

    void PrintTime(double num, int i)
    {
        constexpr double SECONDS_IN_HOUR = 3600;
        constexpr double SECONDS_IN_MINUTE = 60;

        double totalSeconds = num;
        int hours = totalSeconds / SECONDS_IN_HOUR;
        int minutes = (totalSeconds - (hours * SECONDS_IN_HOUR)) / SECONDS_IN_MINUTE;
        int seconds = totalSeconds - (hours * SECONDS_IN_HOUR) - (minutes * SECONDS_IN_MINUTE);

        std::cout << "Elapsed time for " << i << ": " << hours << "h, " << minutes << "m, " << seconds << "s\n";
    }

}

int main()
{
    constexpr unsigned int MAX_NUM_CHECK = 10000000;
    
    for (int i = 1000000; i <= MAX_NUM_CHECK; i++)
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        int digitIndex = 1;

        // Simplifying this to move to the next i in the loop early:
        //      if i % 2 then the last digit is a 0, 2, 4, 6, or 8 and is therefore divisible by 2
        //      if i % 5 then the last digit is 0 or 5 and is therefore divisible by 5
        if (i % 2 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
        {
            std::cout << i << " not prime" << '\n';
            auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
            PrintTime(elapsed_seconds.count(), i);
            continue;
        }

        bool isPrime = true;
        int divisionNumber = 3;
        int floorNum = floorSqrt(i);
        while (divisionNumber <= floorNum && isPrime)
        {
            if (divisionNumber % 5 == 0)
            {
                divisionNumber += 2;
                continue;
            }

            int number = 0;
            int totalDigits = getTotalDigits(i);
            // This section does the division necessary to iterate through each digit of the 1 to N number
            // Example: Think of dividing 124 into 123456 on paper and how you would iterate through that process

            while (digitIndex <= totalDigits)
            {
                number *= 10;
                number += getIndexDigit(i, digitIndex);
                number %= divisionNumber;
                digitIndex++;
            }

            if (number == 0)
            {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
            divisionNumber += 2;
        }

        if (isPrime)
            std::cout << "N = " << i << " is prime." << '\n';
        else
            std::cout << i << " not prime" << '\n';

        auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
        PrintTime(elapsed_seconds.count(), i);

    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, The biggest number your could get using a 64 bit unsigned integer type is `1234567891011121314`, ie, `N = 14`.  You're going to need big number library if you want to try larger `N`'s.

Comment: @NathanOliver The code breaks down the large number in a way of only using digits. As long as the number of digits of 1 to N is < MAX_UNSIGNED_INT. This is done in the getIndexDigit function.

Answer (score 4):

Its nice to see you are working on the same question I pondered few months ago.
Please refer to [question posted in Math Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4247785/smallest-prime-number-made-of-consecutive-numbers-as-its-digits-in-decimal-repre) for better resources.

TL-DR, 
The number you are looking for is called [SmarandachePrime](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmarandachePrime.html).

As per your code, it seems you are dividing with every number that is not a multiple of 2,5. To optimize you can actually check for n = 6k+1 (  ∈ ℕ ).
unfortunately, it is still not a better approach with respect to the number you are dealing with.

The better approach is to use primality test screening to find probable prime numbers in the sequence and then check whether they are prime or not. These tests take a less time [~(O(k log3n))](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Complexity) to check whether a number is prime or not, using mathematical fundamentals, compared to division. 
there are several libraries that provide functions for primality check.
for python, you can use gmpy2 library, which uses [Miller-Rabin Primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) to find probable primes.

I recommend you to further read about different [Primality tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) here.

Comment: I'm glad to see you are also interested in this.  I did realize a mistake though while reviewing my code. I realized I was using sqrt of **N** instead of sqrt of the number 1 ... **N**.  Without using the larger number libraries or implementing some complex mathematics, I am limited in checking for divisors 3 through UINT64_MAX. I am also limited for **N** <= UINT64_MAX.  I did change my code however to implement this and found that up to **N** = UINT64_MAX are not prime.  This is larger than the previously found up to **N** = 1,000,000.

Comment: i am afraid ,you might be doing something wrong somewhere, it will generally take hours , if not days to actually check if a number of this scale is prime.

just to make sure, by N =12 you mean number is "123456789101112"
so for N= 1,000,000 will have ~6,000,000 digits in it.

please check your algorithm or update your complete code so I will check if it alright.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing one very important check, and it's the division by 3:

A number can be divided by 3 is the sum of the numbers can be divided by 3, and your number consists of all numbers from 1 to N.
The sum of all numbers from 1 to N equals:

```
N * (N+1) / 2
```

This means that, if N or N+1 can be divided by 3, then your number cannot be prime.

So before you do anything, check `MOD(N,3)` and `MOD(N+1,3)`. If either one of them equals zero, you can't have a prime number.